# Turn Python Kivy program into C code

Tags: python, kivy, cython

I am thinking of developing a Python program with a GUI library such as Kivy. As the program will be commercial, I would like to protect the source code. There are other methods of protection including license keys and license servers, and these would be employed as well. I know that Cython compiles Python code to C. Would it be possible to have this code converted to C?

EDIT: I was asked for some example code. Here is a basic example from the [Kivy Website](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html):

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Why not protect the source code with an appropriate license?

Comment: Please post some code what you try

Comment: @timgeb I would be using a license key to protect the code as well.

Comment: @Rajarshi Das editing post with some example code

Comment: Just because the program is commercial, it doesn't mean you have to obfuscate the code. Obfuscation is overrated.

Comment: @jilgeza I know, but there can also be some speed optimizations when converting the code to C. Don't think that I won't be employing other protection methods with the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. For more information, read the [cython documentation](http://docs.cython.org/).

Comment: so you can include most external libraries when cythonizing Python code?

Comment: could you possibly link to the specific page?

Comment: What specific page? What you want is exactly what cython does, you should read its documentation and try an example.

Comment: I know what cython does. The page I would like is how to include external python libraries (in this case Kivy) when the Python code is cythonized. Is it automatically detected?

Comment: No, cython compiles the files you tell it to. You could cythonize all of kivy if you wanted, but why do you actually need to? Kivy is already open source, its code is not a secret, only your code needs to be compiled for what you want.

Comment: Yes, only my code should be compiled. I understand that. However, I would need to import Kivy into my Python script. Wouldn't I need to cythonize Kivy in the process?

Comment: No, you wouldn't. The C code you get from cython uses python's normal internal C representations, and ultimately an import is a set of C functions that can be called from cython with exactly the same effect as in cython code.

Comment: So I could cythonize the code example above and Kivy would automatically be included?

Comment: No, cython compiles a specific file. The dependencies of that file are unaffected (and probably don't even need to be present - cython doesn't actually run the code).

Comment: So I cythonize my single script then compile the C code with GC ?

Comment: Read the cython documentation and try some simple examples, this will make the compilation process clear.

Comment: Hi, were you able to make the kivy hello world example run when cythonized? So far I couldn't. It compiles, runs, everything appears to be working, but after some kivy ouput, the app ends with no error or window/widget created whatsoever.

Comment: There. Fixed it. The problem was the module name. When not embedding, and instead you run from a stub .py with a single import to your module (the one that used to be run as __main__) the module name the module see is, obvioulsy, not __main__ anymore, but the module name itself. Changing the usual if __name__ == '__main__':  for your module name would do it, as long as you don't import the module anywhere else. The best way would be to --embed via cython cmd line, that way you can "run" the module without modifying a single char, since the __name__ would be kept as __main__. Hope it helps any1